# assigning table cells with API dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a table that i'm trying to fill cells with dynamic data from another website like a date field for example.

```
<tr> 
<td><b>Date</b></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td>value</td> 
</tr>
```

when I look at the source for the date on the other webiste. I go to call it by it's element.

```
var x = document.getElementById("Scheduled_Date__c");
```

so the code then looks like this:

```
<script>
<tr> 
    <td><b>Date</b></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
    <td var x = document.getElementById("Scheduled_Date__c");></td> 
    </tr>
</script>
```

but the data field just shows blank. I'm fairly new to HTML coding. am I approaching this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the td element's value and put it in the cell.

```
var x = document.getElementById("Scheduled_Date__c"); //gets the element
x.innerText //is the value of the td element that goes into the cell.
```